# React native - The signal SIGILL has a non-Crashlytics handler (<redacted>). This will interfere with reporting

Tags: ios, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric

When I add `Crashlytics` to react native project (iOS) and run on the real device. I see the log:

`The signal SIGILL has a non-Crashlytics handler (<redacted>).  This will interfere with reporting.`

It sounds dangerous but I found no document about it. If you guy know what it is and how to fix it, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same message in expoKit project, did you find out what was causing a problem?

Comment: @Lucky_girl: Sorry, I try to setup again but no hope. If you find something, please let me know. I will do the same too

Comment: I'm getting the same warning with Instabug, even though `CrashReporting.enabled` is set to false

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one uncaught exception handler in iOS. It sounds like you have two types of crash reporting setup and this would cause this issue.

Comment: @ToddBumer: I only add Fabric to my project. Thank you for your comment, I think I will double check if there is any lib that also have the crash report